# Scipy pivoted QR permutation

Tags: python, performance, scipy

I have to solve a lot of linear systems using the Scipy pivoted QR-decomposition.

```py
Q, R, perm = scipy.linalg.qr(PW, pivoting=True, mode='full')
```

During solving the system I reorder the solution using a 
permutation matrix using the function below.

```py
def pvec2pmat(vec):

   n = len(vec)
   P = np.zeros((n, n))
   counter = 0
   for i in range(0, n):
       for j in range(0, n):
           if j == vec[counter]:
               P[i, j] = 1.0
               counter = counter + 1
               break
   return P.T
```

Unfortunately, this turns out to be very slow and the code spend a lot of time generating these matrices.
Is it possible to speedup this function?

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to answer your question, as I do not know what your code is supposed to do. Furthermore, there seems to be no connection to the title. If you understand you correctly, you ask me to optimize the given function, without even knowing what the input is.

I will assume that `vec` is expected to be a 1-dimensional integer array. In this case your second loop is quite unnecessary. There are two caseses:

1. vec[counter] in range(0, n)
   In this case you set P[i, vec[counter]] to one, and increase the counter (due to the break statement)
2. vec[counter] not in range(0, n)
   The counter will never be increases, as the if statement will never be True. Thus, we ignore the rest of `vec` and return the matrix.

Therefor a first simplification would be:

```
def pvec2pmat(vec):

   n = len(vec)
   P = np.zeros((n, n))
   counter = 0
   for i in range(0, n):
       if vec[counter] in range(0, n):
           P[i, vec[counter]] = 1.0
           counter += 1
       else:
           return P.T
   return P.T
```

So the relevant part of `vec` is only till for the first time a value not in `range(0, n)` is reached. We can check this right in the beginning and discard the rest.

We can do this using

```
invalid = (vec < 0) & (vec > 0)
try:
   first_invalid = np.flatnonzero(invalid)[0]
except IndexError:  # no invalid values
   pass
else:
   vec[:first_invalid]  # keep only till first invalid encounter
```

Now we know that we assign one value for all rows `i <= vec.size`.

So we can simplify the loop

```
for i, vec_val in enumerate(vec):
    P[i, vec_val] = 1
```

This can however also be done using indixing:

```
P[np.arange(vec.size), vec] = 1
```

Finally we realize, that instead of taken the transpose, we can just assign it in the reverse order and get

```
def pvec2pmat(vec): 
    n = len(vec) 
    P = np.zeros((n, n))
    invalid = (vec < 0) & (vec > 0)
    try:
       first_invalid = np.flatnonzero(invalid)[0]
    except IndexError:  # no invalid values
       pass
    else:
       vec[:first_invalid]  # keep only till first invalid encounter
    P[vec, np.arange(vec.size)] = 1 
    return P
```

A quick timing:

```
vec = np.arange(1000)
np.random.shuffle(vec)

# your version
128 ms ± 2.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# my version
%timeit pvec2pmat(vec)
379 µs ± 22.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# for this simple example of a permutation, we can of course resort to
# siple indexing
%timeit np.eye(vec.size)[:, vec]
8.89 ms ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For this particular example, my code takes 1/300 the time of your version. Depending on your need, another large speedup can be achieved, if `P` is chosen as an `boolean` matrix, and we assign `True`.